# General characteristics of rules

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-language

I'm starting a research on **rules** -- whether moral rules, laws, game rules, etc.

Can anyone point me to references which investigate rules as their object?

---

EDIT (in response to @YechiamWeiss )

@YechiamWeiss, thank you for your comment. That is precisely the point. I haven't found yet any work which addresses **rules** in the general sense.

For instance, I may present two working hypotheses about rules themselves:

. all rules are constructs;

. there can be no self-implemented rules.

These two hypotheses are perhaps self-evident. But my underlying question is: **are there other common characteristics to all rules?** I did not find any references discussing this question, and that's what I asked here.

I agree, it is a very broad question. But I submit that it is a valid question: can anyone point me to authors who have studied rules as an object in themselves, as opposed to rules in specific contexts?

Comment: Useful : [Wittgenstein : Rule-following and Private Language](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#RuleFollPrivLang).

Comment: Thanks, @MauroALLEGRANZA, this seems like a good starting point indeed.

Comment: Hi Luiz, welcome to Phil.SE. The question as it is currently postulated is way too broad for anyone to give a proper answer to. Consider narrowing your question to a more specific set of rules you'd like information about, and ask a specific question (not generally "someone who talks about rules"). Currently I'm voting to close this question as *too broad*.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss , I edited my question to address your comments.

Comment: Not much cogent can be said about "rules in general", moral rules and rules in games have little interesting in common. You can look at [Routledge's](https://www.rep.routledge.com/articles/thematic/normativity/v-1) and [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normative) articles on normativity for some generalities, but to get to something substantive you'll have to narrow the scope to something more cohesive than a loose colloquial catchall.

Comment: @Conifold perhaps writings like Wittgenstein can help him, as Mauro suggested.

Comment: Luiz I edited the title and tags to reflect your edits (which by the way made the question clearer).

Comment: This is not a particularly well-studied area. Most philosophers merely presume the existence of rules as a kind of natural law; they might quibble over how they manifest, but they don't question the 'fact' of them. I could go on for a good long while on this topic myself, but I've never published anything on the topic do I don't really count as a 'source'. Wittgenstein is clearly the place to start, though I've never seen anyone who credibly advances his insights into rules.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss,  thanks for the editing.